# Angular: Watch Service for data changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service defined as something like this:

```
appServices.service('SharedData', function() {
    var data = {};

    function setContacts(contacts) {
        data.contacts = contacts;
    };

    function getContacts() {
        return data.contacts;
    };

    return {
        setContacts: setContacts,
        getContacts: getContacts
    };
});
```

In another controller, I access the data as follows:

```
$scope.contacts = SharedData.getContacts();
```

This is all well and good - but I'd like `$scope.contacts` to be alerted and update it's data whenever the data in SharedData changes.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: you could use an event...

Answer (score 3):

Try an explicit watch:

`$scope.$watch(function() {
  return SharedData.getContacts();
}, function(newContacts) {
  // Do something with newContacts.
});`

If elements of the collection can change without the entire collection object changing identity (I assume an `Array` or `Object`), you'll need to use `$scope.$watchCollection`, though that is substantially slower than plain `$watch`, so avoid if you can make the entire collection change at once.

Note that it might be nicer design to expose a function to the scope that simply returns the current contacts:

`$scope.getContacts = function() { return SharedData.getContacts(); };`

If you need notification within `SharedData`, you can inject `$rootScope` into it and put the `$watch` onto that.

Comment: With the warning that a simple watch will not trigger if an individual contact has been updated. You need to use `$scope.$watchCollection` if you are also interested in that.

Comment: @floribon I don't care for using `$watch` in this manner -- running such a method on every digest cycle just seems wrong.  However, the way the service is written, a simple `$watch` will work because the entire collection is getting reseated every time with `setContacts`.  I hope you'll agree that `$watchCollection` is a very painful way to go, as it potentially iterates through each child looking for changes.  http://jsperf.com/angularjs-watchcollection-on-large-dataset

Comment: Nice! I am new to Angular and wrote my answer without knowing about this.

Comment: @MichaelHays I totally agree and didn't say you were wrong! I jsut added my comment "as a warning" in case OP expect to update the contacts individually (which is still possible after getting them). `watchCollection` does shallow object properties watch: that costs a bit more but still very far from a deep watch (using `$watch` with the last parameter set to true), and shouldn't be a real concern. But I still agree with your point and would personally go with a listener approach. I upvoted you before posting my comment :)

Comment: Oops, I thought that last comment for which I answered came from the answer poster (similar names). I'm consuded now. Anyway I upvoted all the answers before commenting as they are all ok so don't get ofended.

Comment: Haha... hey it happens!  :-D  For the record, I think your warning is completely appropriate.  Using broadcast is probably one of the more efficient ways to do this, as it's kind of the built in way to create these top down listeners.

Comment: Updated my answer with the point about `$watchCollection`, both the mention and the performance warning. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

Be wary of abusing it, but this is just the sort of thing that `$rootScope` is for:

```
appServices.service('SharedData', function($rootScope) {
  var data = {};
  function setContacts(contacts) {
    data.contacts = contacts;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('contacts-changed', contacts);
  };
  ...
```

Now, in any scope you'd like, you can register for this event:

```
function($scope) {
  $scope.$on('contacts-changed', function(eventObj) {...});
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. Does the passed in var `nv` have any particular meaning?

Comment: Ha!  You caught a mistake.  I use `nv` to represent "new value," but in this case, it is better named something like `evt`, and is the event object:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: That makes more sense, thanks. Another question: what would be considered abusing this technique? I'll eventually use it to broadcast a dozen or more "changed" events.

Comment: My first thought is, "does your technique increase the readability of the code?"  My second thought is, "if it reduces the readability of the code, is the increase in maintenance offset with justifiable performance gains?"  If the answer to either question is "no," then you might be abusing the feature.  Unless you are in a tight animation loop, what you are suggesting sounds fine.

Comment: Finally getting a chance to respond. Question #1: at first yes, but it eventually became spaghetti code and difficult to follow. I learned about using the controllerAs (`MainCtrl as main`) syntax and because my controllers are nested I was easily able to access parent models (`main.customer`) in sub-controllers. It's so much cleaner and requires no special broadcasting. Thanks for you help being cautious!

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to define a function in your service which lets you register a callback to be called when `setContacts` is called (`onContactsUpdated` below). This solution is not perfect (for example, it only lets you register a single 'handler'), but should get you on the right track. You could tweak it if it needs to be used in multiple places.

```
appServices.service('SharedData', function() {
    var data = {};

    function setContacts(contacts) {
        data.contacts = contacts;
        if(typeof(data.contactsUpdatedCallback) !== "undefined"){
            data.contactsUpdatedCallback();
        }
    };

    function getContacts() {
        return data.contacts;
    };

    function onContactsUpdated(callback){
        data.contactsUpdatedCallback = callback;
    };

    return {
        setContacts: setContacts,
        getContacts: getContacts,
        onContactsUpdated: onContactsUpdated
    };
});
```

Then in your controller:

```
SharedData.onContactsUpdated(function(){
    //do something with updated SharedData.getContacts()
});
```